# Error importing QGIS modules in standalone script: from qgis._gui import * ImportError: The specified module could not be found

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to run the following script (following Gary Sherman's PyQGIS Programmer's Guide). It is supposed to create a standalone PyQT window that displays a .shp in the QgsMapCanvas without opening QGIS.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame, QGridLayout, QMainWindow
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer

app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.22.7", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

main_win = QMainWindow()
frame = QFrame(main_win)
main_win.setCentralWidget(frame)
grid_layout = QGridLayout(frame)

map_canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
grid_layout.addWidget(map_canvas)

layer = QgsVectorLayer(
    'C:/data/alaska.shp',\
    'alaska', 'ogr')
    
prj = QgsProject()
prj.addMapLayer(layer)

map_canvas.setLayers([layer])
map_canvas.zoomToFullExtent()

main_win.show()

app.exec_()
```

However, when running the script I get the following error:

[image]

Line 25 in the gui_*init*_.py shows this:
[image: Line25Image]

Can anyone help me get past this obstacle and load up a basic standalone QGIS app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't said *how* you are running your standalone script, but my guess is that you need to set up your pyqgis environment, for which on Windows you can use a batch file. The batch file will depend on QGIS version and installation method, but the file below *should* work for you.

```
@echo off
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.7
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
@echo off
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\bin
path %PATH%;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Qt5\bin
path %PATH%;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Scripts
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis-ltr
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
rem Set VSI cache to be used as buffer, see #6448
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\python
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python39
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins

cmd.exe
```

This example is for an LTR standalone (not OSGeo4W) install. Be aware that if your version is not an LTR, you would need to replace `qgis-ltr` with `qgis` in the batch file paths.

If you save this batch file in the same location as your python script `.py` file, when you double click on the batch file, it will open a command prompt with pyqgis environment correctly set. You can then type 'python' followed by the name of your standalone script e.g. `python scriptname.py` to run your standalone script.

Comment: Thanks, that works great. My issue was I had set up a similar batch file (same instructions were given in the book) and ran it but I wasn't aware that I had to run the .py script from the console. Instead I closed the console, opened the script in my IDE and tried to run it from there (receiving the above error). How would this work for a third-party user if I were to build an standalone qgis-dependent application and try to deploy it?

Comment: @Jiinglelocks, you can edit the last line of the batch file to start an IDE e.g. Pycharm or Pyscripter. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371516/configuring-pycharm-to-work-with-qgis-libraries. There are lots of examples on gisse and on the broader Web. For deployment, I have not tried it with standalone pyqgis apps, but maybe you could try packaging to an executable with a tool such as py2exe.